# CV, babel problem

Tags: babel, greek, cv, english

I want to make a cv with Greek and English language. The problem is that the english appear with Greek font. Here is a short example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, a4paper]{moderncv}  

\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\moderncvstyle{casual} 

\moderncvcolor{green}  

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\name{Πέτρος}{Μουρούζης}

\title{Βιογραφικό}   

\address{Κωνσταντίνου Καραμανλή 77}{54642}{Θεσσαλονίκη}

\phone[mobile]{697.4936.202}   

\phone[fixed]{2310.911.890}                    

\email{mr.mourouzis@gmail.com} 

\homepage{www.mourouzisdental.gr} 
\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Eκπαίδευση}

\cvitemwithcomment{2013-2018}{PhD in Operative Dentistry}{Aristotle
University of Thessaloniki}

\cvitemwithcomment{2011-2014}{MSc in Operative Dentistry}{Aristotle
University of Thessaloniki}

\cvitemwithcomment{2002-2007}{B.Sc in Dentistry}{Aristotle University of
Thessaloniki}

\cvitemwithcomment{1998-2002}{B.Sc in Physical Education}{Aristotle
University of Thessaloniki}

\section{Ξένες Γλώσσες}

\cvitemwithcomment{Γλώσσα}{Αγγλικά}{Επίπεδο C2}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example of english language with greek font]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having `\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}` means that `greek` `babel` settings are the default for the whole document. Since `greek` option sets/switches font encoding to `LGR`, before writing in English you should set/change `babel` context to `english` (will automatically switch font encoding to `T1`). You can use `\selectlanguage{...}`, `\foreignlanguage{...}{...}` and similar `babel`'s commands (check the `babel`'s docs).

For example...

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{green}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\name{Πέτρος}{Μουρούζης}
\title{Βιογραφικό}
\address{Κωνσταντίνου Καραμανλή 77}{54642}{Θεσσαλονίκη}
\phone[mobile]{697.4936.202}
\phone[fixed]{2310.911.890}
\email{mr.mourouzis@gmail.com}
\homepage{www.mourouzisdental.gr}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Eκπαίδευση}
\selectlanguage{english}
\cvitemwithcomment{2013-2018}{PhD in Operative Dentistry}{Aristotle University of Thessaloniki}
\cvitemwithcomment{2011-2014}{MSc in Operative Dentistry}{Aristotle University of Thessaloniki}
\cvitemwithcomment{2002-2007}{B.Sc in Dentistry}{Aristotle University of Thessaloniki}
\cvitemwithcomment{1998-2002}{B.Sc in Physical Education}{Aristotle University of Thessaloniki}

\selectlanguage{greek}
\section{Ξένες Γλώσσες}
\cvitemwithcomment{Γλώσσα}{Αγγλικά}{Επίπεδο C2}
\end{document}
```

Also, there is nothing special about `moderncv` in this context. Your issue is simply writing the multiscript and multilingual document in proper way.

Kind regards, Ivan

Answer (score 1):

First of all, avoid `utf8x`. Then, mark the parts you want in English.

For the email and web address, an indirect method has to be used, because `\textlatin` conflicts with `hyperref` trying to make links out of them.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage[scale=0.75,footskip=60pt]{geometry}

\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{green}

\newrobustcmd{\emailaddress}{\textlatin{mr.mourouzis@gmail.com}}
\newrobustcmd{\webaddress}{\textlatin{www.mourouzisdental.gr}}


\name{Πέτρος}{Μουρούζης}
\title{Βιογραφικό}
\address{Κωνσταντίνου Καραμανλή 77}{54642}{Θεσσαλονίκη}
\phone[mobile]{697.4936.202}
\phone[fixed]{2310.911.890}
\email{\emailaddress}
\homepage{\webaddress}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Eκπαίδευση}

\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}
\cvitemwithcomment{2013-2018}
  {PhD in Operative Dentistry}
  {Aristotle University of Thessaloniki}

\cvitemwithcomment{2011-2014}
  {MSc in Operative Dentistry}
  {Aristotle University of Thessaloniki}

\cvitemwithcomment{2002-2007}
  {B.Sc in Dentistry}
  {Aristotle University of Thessaloniki}

\cvitemwithcomment{1998-2002}
  {B.Sc in Physical Education}
  {Aristotle University of Thessaloniki}
\end{otherlanguage*}

\section{Ξένες Γλώσσες}

\cvitemwithcomment{Γλώσσα}
  {Αγγλικά}
  {Επίπεδο C2}

\end{document}
```

I set `footskip` in order to avoid the warning it is set to a too small value.

[image]