# Greek letters don't appear in overleaf document even though greek babel package is inserted

Tags: compiling, babel, overleaf, greek

I am trying to modify the following overleaf latex document:

[1.5-column-cv](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/1-dot-5-column-cv/rpcbqtrsgbxm)

I want to write everything in greek so after doins some search I inserted at the preamble the below packages:

```
\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
```

However,the greek letters that I am typing won't appear at the compiled document. The latin letters appear in a greek style making everything a total mess. I suspect this has to do with some packages influencing some others or some thing I don't know and moreover can't discover. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please check if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440366/cv-babel-problem helps; otherwise you should post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using Xelatex as my compiler along with \usepackage{polyglossia}.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
    \setsansfont{FreeSans}
    \setmonofont{FreeMono}

\title{Title}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
 Κείμενο στα Ελληνικά.
 
 This is a text in english 
 
 \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Outputs:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a very frequent problem with the non-standard `LGR` encoding, which requires tricky hacks. Currently the best option is to resort to `luatex` (my favourite) or `xetex`, as shown in the following example. As you can see, you have to remove `fontenc` and `inputenc` and declare a font.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[greek]{babel}

\babelfont{rm}{Alegreya}

\begin{document}

Ελληνικό κείμενο. Latin text.

\end{document}
```

[image]